General steps to induce special functions from the Lie group/algebra representations
I will show one exact examples.
For harmonic oscillator,we have ladder operators $a_\pm=X\mp iP$.Then let's consider the following steps.

For $\langle x|a_-|0\rangle=0$, if we impose $a_-=X+iP$ then immediately find the equation $(x+i\frac{d}{dx}) \langle x|0\rangle$ and then we found the solution for $\psi_0$

We know $a_+|0\rangle=k|1\rangle$ for some constant $k$,then we successfully obtain all $\psi_n$ which is the $n$th Hermitian polynomial.


And now I have two questions.

How to construct general "ladder operators"(in fact I don't know whether we still have them or we should change their names) and whether the corresponding steps always work well? For example,the ladder operator for $so(3)$ Lie algebra can be $L_\pm =L_1\mp i L_2$, but seems the corresponding equation for groud state wave function $$[z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+i(x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}) ] \langle x,y,z|0 \rangle =0$$ is not solvable...

What are the corresponding mathematical steps and terms? I know two important things are

finding the casimir operators which are commutes to all generators
finding the Cartan subalgebra which is the maximum abelian subalgebra



But in fact I don't know how to do the two steps systematically. And I also don't know what is the following steps if I finished the two steps. Can someone show me some general steps? Most materials online are to tough for me...

Materials online are abusive, and cannot supplant a good text like, in your case, Sakurai & Napolitano. There are advanced texts like Vilenkin, but you appear to be trying to bypass a solid course by web-surfing.

@CosmasZachos I have no idea what you are complaining; yes, there are often horrible online resources, but on this topic the resources are, on the contrary, better online than in textbook form, paradoxically. The reason is that it is of limited interest for introductory texts, hence why you had to refer to an advanced text. One avenue for this ladder operator is using the LRLP vector. Another avenue is the SDIH factorisation. Neither is easy, and it seems like the generalisation to the Dirac equation is seriously horrible.

@CosmasZachos  I think Vilenkin is too tough. For Sakurai its not helpful in this topic.
And I think treat these topics with fully mathematically rigor is ridiculous, the only important thing is the core part and its application, or every researchers should know set theory and mathematical logic well before they study calculus

I disagree that the source of your question does not rely on the S&N text. You make it sound as though it does on Fulton&Harris. Nope! What about this WP article leaves you confused?

I'd be remiss if I failed to detail the mathy Representation of Lie groups and special functions, by N. Ja. Vilenkin and A. U. Klimyk (translated from the Russian by V. A. Groza and A. A. Groza), Math. Appl., Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht. v 1: Simplest Lie groups, special functions and integral transforms, v 72, 1991,   608 pp.,  ISBN 0-7923-1466-2; v 2: Class I representations, special functions, and integral transforms, vol. 74, 1992,   607 pp.,   ISBN 0-7923- 1492-1; v 3: Classical and quantum groups and special functions, v 75, 1992,   634 pp.,   ISBN 0-7923-1493-X.

(My tribute to my teacher, Bargmann.) No genuine research can eschew them.

@naturallyinconsistent   I did not take the bridge from 1. to 2. as an invitation into unexplored regions of  the multitextured patchwork of modality flotsam  spanning LRL and SDIH/SSQM factorization. I judged that the OP took a wrong turn from the two-sphere to the plane, which I addressed in my answer.

The answer to your 1. is implicitly given in this answer from the all-crucial section of S&N, an over complete treatment. Indeed, in units of $\hbar=1$, $L_{\pm}$ are bona-fide ladder operators,
$$
[L_z, L_{\pm}]= \pm L_{\pm},
$$
since they raise or lower the eigenvalues of $L_z$, the Cartan subalgebra labels.
In spherical coordinates, so on the two-sphere,
$$
\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_+= e^{-i\phi}(\partial_\theta -i\cot\theta \partial_\phi) \langle \hat {\mathbf n}|,\\
\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_-= e^{i\phi}(\partial_\theta +i\cot\theta \partial_\phi)\langle \hat {\mathbf n}| ,\\  
 \langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_z= -i\partial_\phi \langle \hat {\mathbf n}|~,\\ 
\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|{\mathbf L}^2= -\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\left (\sin\!\theta ~\partial_\theta ~ \sin\!\theta ~\partial_\theta +\partial_\phi^2 \right)\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|.$$
Now, acting on null eigenstates of ${\mathbf L}^2$ and $L_z$,  $|l=0,m=0\rangle$, yields
$$
0=\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_-|0,0\rangle = e^{i\phi}(\partial_\theta -i\cot\theta ~\partial_\phi)\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|0,0\rangle ,
$$
solvable by a constant $Y^0_0(\theta, \phi)$, conventionally normalized to $1/2\sqrt \pi$.$^\natural$
To thence obtain the next higher l triplet of spherical harmonics,
$\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|1,-1\rangle= Y^{-1}_1$,
$\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|1,0\rangle= Y^{0}_1$,
$\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|1,1\rangle= Y^{1}_1$,
you repeat
$$
0=\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_-|1,-1\rangle = e^{i\phi}(\partial_\theta -i\cot\theta ~\partial_\phi)\langle \hat {\mathbf n}|1,-1\rangle ,
$$
solvable by $Y^{-1}_1\propto e^{-i\phi} \sin\theta $, and onwards as per your oscillator recursion algorithm:
$$
Y^0_1\propto \langle \hat {\mathbf n}|L_+|1,-1\rangle \propto e^{i\phi} (\partial_\theta -i\cot\theta~ \partial_\phi) Y^{-1}_1= 2\cos\theta, 
$$
etc... Work out the next step in the recursion. Observe the Legendre logic of how the irrep terminates.
It is in complete formal analogy to the harmonic oscillator, once you appreciate the representations are finite-dimensional,   by  contrast, and why.
That book, S&N is a must, for these types of questions.

$^\natural$Of course, the kernel of this differential operator includes all $Y^{-l}_l$ for all integers $l$.

Thank you for the answer. You're definitely right, and I now finally realise what do you mean in your cited answer.
